# A unity of gamers try to revolt against economic system

Tags: story-identification, computers

I am searching for a book that I read a few years ago.

I know that it was written between 2008-2014 and that the author's name sounded Russian.

Cover: A black cover with a computer (comic style) and a few red accents.

Plot: There is a parallel economy system. This system is ruled by the game companies. So a group of Asian teenagers have to work for game-gold, to earn some money. But a few want to rebel against it and they form a opposition. This opposition has gamers from around the world.

I also remember some game names out of the book:

- Mushroom Kingdom
- Mech...

Some treatment locations:

- USA
- India
- Indonesia

Does anybody remember this book?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your description sounds very much like Cory Doctorow's *For the Win*.

[Goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7241373-for-the-win) summary:

> At any hour of the day or night, millions of people around the globe are engrossed in multiplayer online games, questing and battling to win virtual “gold,” jewels, and precious artifacts. Meanwhile, others seek to exploit this vast shadow economy, running electronic sweatshops in the world’s poorest countries, where countless “gold farmers,” bound to their work by abusive contracts and physical threats, harvest virtual treasure for their employers to sell to First World gamers who are willing to spend real money to skip straight to higher-level gameplay.
>
> Mala is a brilliant 15-year-old from rural India whose leadership skills in virtual combat have earned her the title of “General Robotwalla.” In Shenzen, heart of China’s industrial boom, Matthew is defying his former bosses to build his own successful gold-farming team. Leonard, who calls himself Wei-Dong, lives in Southern California, but spends his nights fighting virtual battles alongside his buddies in Asia, a world away. All of these young people, and more, will become entangled with the mysterious young woman called Big Sister Nor, who will use her experience, her knowledge of history, and her connections with real-world organizers to build them into a movement that can challenge the status quo.

[Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_the_Win)
[ISFDB link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1098147)

Comment: Yes this is exactly the book :) thx. How did you found it? Did you know it or do made a research? (My research failed)

Comment: I guessed the author and then went to bibliography section of his wikipedia article

Comment: Incidentally, a Google search string of 'science fiction "online game" economy "mushroom kingdom"' also finds it. :)

Comment: I tried so many variations of the key words... Maybe i am just to stupid :D

Comment: Google-Fu is a mysterious art. :-P

Comment: Ah so...another purveyor of Google-Fu...saved me, keeps me employed, makes me the golden font of all knowledge! MWAHAHAHA... errr

Comment: The book is also available online for free (under CC license): http://craphound.com/ftw/Cory_Doctorow_-_For_the_Win.htm .